# Visa with recent activity?

Tags: payment-cards

I've been travelling a lot and I find it slightly irritating that my VISA provider doesn't provide info for my activity for the last ~2 days. I guess the reasoning is they are waiting for it to "post" because it may just be a verification not a charge, but still it changes my balance immediately and it can be confusing what is doing that so I know when to expect the funds to be released back into my account.

Comment: This is about the VISA credit card, right?  Not really associated with the 'visas' tag...  Consider an edit to clarify please.

Comment: Is this a visa credit or visa debit card? (They can behave differently)

Answer (score 2):

I am not a credit card expert but it happened to me when using both debit and credit cards abroad. Verifications that would not change my balance at home (or perhaps be cancelled after a few minutes…) looked like a regular transaction, only to be rolled back later (e.g. when filling up gas I would have a first transaction for €150 and another one with the real price paid; the amount for the first one would be released back to my account or my card a week later). It took up to 7-10 days in some cases. I am not aware of any way to avoid this.